# ¿Como crear una funcion que diga si son o no correctas las respuestas de un cuestionario?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un cuestionario de la siguiente manera

Creo un array que contenga dentro los objetos de mi cuestionario

```
    var cuestionario = [{
    pregunta: 'pregunta1',
    opciones: {
      a: 'opcionA1',
      b: 'opcionB1',
      c: 'opcionC1',
    },
    correcta: 'a',
  },
  {
    pregunta: 'pregunta2',
    opciones: {
      a: 'opcionA2',
      b: 'opcionB2',
      c: 'opcionC2',
    },
    correcta: 'b',
  }

]
```

¿Como puedo crear esta funcion que compruebe si la opcion seleccionada es correcta?.

El parametro "OpcionSeleccionada" es uno de los String del objeto "Opciones".

```
function comprobarRespuesta(opcionSeleccionada) {

}
```

¿Hay alguna forma mas elegante de hacer esto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por como lo tienes planteado parece bastante sencillo, aunque seguramente a tu función también le hace falta recibir ya sea un índice del arreglo de preguntas o una entrada de dicho arreglo para que sepa con qué pregunta está trabajando (A menos que la pregunta actual esté almacenada en una variable externa). En caso de que la función también recibiera el objeto con datos de la pregunta, la función podría plantearse así:

```
function comprobarRespuesta(entradaArreglo, opcionSeleccionada) {
    return entradaArreglo.opciones[entradaArreglo.correcta] === opcionSeleccionada
}
```

Como ves, entradaArreglo.correcta contendrá una cadena correspondiente a la opción correcta ('a', 'b' o 'c') y dicha cadena se puede usar como clave para el objeto **opciones** pare obtener la respuesta concreta, de manera que solo faltaría comparar dicha respuesta en contra del argumento recibido.

Comment: Muy clara tu respuesta , gracias por la ayuda